# Generic class confuse

Tags: java, generics

I have 2 abstract classes: `Screen` and `World`. Both implements `IState`.
So I want use generic type for concrete classes in order to bypass class casting.

```
public abstract class World<S extends Screen> implements IState{/*body*/}

public abstract class Screen<W extends World> implements IState{/*body*/}

public final class SomeWorld extends World<SomeScreen> {}

public final class SomeScreen extends Screen<SomeWorld> {}
```

There is no error but a warning at 2nd abstract class which tell me I'm missing the generic argument. So I put  to temporary keep the warning

```
public abstract class World<S extends Screen<?>> implements IState{/*body*/}

public abstract class Screen<W extends World<?>> implements IState{/*body*/}
```

Am I using generic in the right way or any better solution?

EDIT: Assume that in SomeWorld class have the doSomething() method which not declare in the abstract World method. How could I call world.doSomething() in somescreen instance without casting: 
    ((SomeWorld) world).doSomething()

Comment: Seems like you don't need generic here, what do you exactly mean by *"So I want use generic type for concrete classes in order to bypass class casting."*

Comment: Are you sure you want that cycle in your class design?

Comment: Can't say whether you're using generics properly without a lot more detail about what you're trying to achieve. Please elaborate, especially to the relationship between `Screen` and `World` (why you need each type to depend on the other).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the elaboration.

If you have a variable (or expression) with a type of `World` and you want to invoke a method that's defined in `SomeWorld` on it, you have only two options:

Cast: `((SomeWorld) world).doSomething();`

Reflection: `world.getClass().getMethod("doSomething").invoke(world);`

Java won't let you directly reference fields or methods of an object that are not declared in whatever type the compiler has deduced for that object at compile time.

Casting allows you to change the expression into one with the required type, so the compiler's requirement is satisfied, but it raises the possibility of a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Reflection allows you to get to those methods when casting isn't possible. (E.g. when you have no idea what type the object is but you want to invoke its `xyz` method if it has one). Various exceptions may be thrown in this case.

BTW, your circular type dependency between `World` and `Screen` is something that is very rarely seen, and therefore highly suspect though not technically incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. that's why I wanna use generic type